# creating an f-string generator expression and with index values

Tags: python, generator

I don't have enough experience with generator expression to figure this out.
I have a list and input statement like so:

```
work = ['Read', 'Write', 'Program', 'Email']
assign = input(f"Select what you have worked on > {(str(x) for x in work)}")
```

The above code is not working! The work list might change. I also want to see a different input message that is more like.

> Select what you have worked on > 0: Read, 1: Write, 2: Program, 3: Email >

How do you recommend getting this input question?

Comment: That's not a list comprehension in the f-string; it's a generator expression. `[str(x) for x in work]`. You don't even need a list comprehension; `work` is *already* a list of `str` values, so you're essentially just making a copy  to use for the prompt.

Comment: list comps look like this: `[x for x in work]` - the str is not needed since those values are already strings.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for, but perhaps `enumerate` and `join` could be helpful?

Comment: Save the argument to `input` for short prompts. You are trying to display a full-blown menu, so I would just generate that using a regular set of calls to `print`, *then* call `input` with a more mundane prompt like "Enter your choice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.join()`:

```
>>> work = ['Read', 'Write', 'Program', 'Email']
>>> f"Select what you have worked on > {', '.join(f'{i}: {x}' for i, x in enumerate(work))}"
'Select what you have worked on > 0: Read, 1: Write, 2: Program, 3: Email'
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. for other looking for the input statement it is:
`assign = input(f"Select what you have worked on > {', '.join(f'{i}: {x}' for i, x in enumerate(work))}")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
work = ['Read', 'Write', 'Program', 'Email']
s = f"Select what you have worked on > {', '.join(work)}"
print(s)
```

Result:

> Select what you have worked on > Read, Write, Program, Email

Comment: bad copy pasta, I had this from trying to explain how list comps actually look in my comment

Comment: Also (you probably already know this) `str.join` takes a generator expression, so no point in creating a list before passing it to `join()`